# How to set table row to trigger jQuery hover event

Tags: php, jquery, html, html-table, hover

When a user hovers the mouse over a table row, to trigger a preview event, only it doesn't react in any way. I think the problem is that the table rows are generated via PHP.

HTML & PHP

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="200">User</th>
        <th width="900">Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    require_once './Classes/MainController.php';
    $mc = MainController::getInstance();
    $threads = $mc->getAllThreads();
    foreach ($threads as $thread) {
        ?>
        <tr id='thread_video_preview'>
            <td><?php print $thread->original_poster; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $thread->description; ?></td>
            <td id='see_thread_video_url' class="hide"><?php print $thread->url; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./Javascript/MainFunctions.js"> HoverPreview();        
  </script>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Jquery

```
 function HoverPreview() {
$('tr#thread_video_preview').hover(function() {
    var url = $(this).$('#see_thread_video_url').html();
    $('#dynamicPreview').html('<iframe width="320" height="240" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + url + '?autoplay=1" frameborder="0""></iframe>')
});
}
```

Comment: `id` if an element must be unique.... so change it to the class...

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here. Firstly, `id` attributes should be unique. If you want to group elements, use a class. Secondly, the location of your `script` tag could cause issues. You should place it in the `head`, or just before `</body>`. Finally, when you set a `src` property of a `script` tag, you cannot place any code in it. You need a separate script tag for that. With all that in mind, try this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Javascript/MainFunctions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javacript">
        $(function() {
            $('tr.thread_video_preview').hover(function() {
                var url = $(this).find('.see_thread_video_url').html();
                $('#dynamicPreview').html('<iframe width="320" height="240" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + url + '?autoplay=1" frameborder="0""></iframe>')
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

In the body:

```
<?php
    require_once './Classes/MainController.php';
    $mc = MainController::getInstance();
    $threads = $mc->getAllThreads();
    foreach ($threads as $thread) { ?>
        <tr class='thread_video_preview'>
            <td><?php print $thread->original_poster; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $thread->description; ?></td>
            <td class='see_thread_video_url' class="hide"><?php print $thread->url; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } 
?>
```

Comment: Changed the position of the your script , changed id to class , no change at all , I posted this question with concerns about the jquery function/script.

Comment: Did you change the `#see_thread_video_url` to `.see_thread_video_url`, and so on, now that they are classes not IDs? Additionally, `$(this).$('#see_thread_video_url')` doesn't make sense – try `$(this).find('.see_thread_video_url')`...

Comment: Did everything you mentioned , nothing happened , I'll pick your answer though because it's more elaborate , and I'll change it to an onclick event

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
    <tr id='thread_video_preview'>
```

To :

```
    <tr class='thread_video_preview'>
```

And in jquery event use

```
$(".thread_video_preview").
```

And I think it is good practice to use properties or event listener in `td` instead of `tr`